# How do I make an image gallery with the effect of zooming selected image and the others scattered

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, css

My javascript code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.img1').mouseover(function(){
    /*  $('.img1').css({ "-webkit-transform ": "scale(2)",
                            "-moz-transform": "scale(2)",
                            "-o-transform": "scale(2)",
                            "transform": "scale(2)"
                        });   */
        $('.img2,.img3,.img4,.img5,.img6,.img7,.img8,.img9,.img14,.img10,.img12,.img13,.img15,.img16,.img17').fadeOut(2500);
     $('.img1').mouseout(function(){
     /* $('.img1').css({"-webkit-transform ": "scale(1)",
                            "-moz-transform": "scale(1)",
                            "-o-transform": "scale(1)",
                            "transform": "scale(1)"});  */
        $('.img2,.img3,.img4,.img5,.img6,.img7,.img8,.img9,.img14,.img10,.img12,.img13,.img15,.img16,.img17').fadeIn(2500);
     });
});
```

It is the code for my first image.

What I want to achieve, is when I hover one image, all the others should get scattered.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather go for pure css, it's much more straight forward. play with the `:hover` selector:

```
.container:hover > div
.container > div:hover
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GKSLk/ (i only wrote for webkit, but you can add more browser support)

Answer (score 0):

try common class for elements 
and different ids for each element
 apply effect in class and apply effect id of hover element